# Как удалить ненужные числа из массива

Tags: python, numpy

Есть массив:

```
array([1.84360190e+00, 3.94438896e+00, 2.83243946e+00, 3.69541585e+00,
       8.76304275e-01, 2.83243946e+00, 4.05242096e+00, 4.04985258e+00,
       2.21859614e+00, 2.19034394e+00, 1.92580059e+00, 2.06706160e+00,
       2.83243946e+00, 3.69541585e+00, 8.76304275e-01, 2.83243946e+00,
       3.25765457e+00, 3.25706630e+00, 3.25765457e+00, 3.25691923e+00,
       3.25699276e+00, 3.25691923e+00, 3.25618388e+00, 3.25758104e+00,
       3.25618388e+00, 3.25544854e+00, 3.25757369e+00, 3.25544854e+00,
       3.25471319e+00, 3.25756633e+00, 3.25471319e+00, 3.26133130e+00,
       3.25755898e+00, 3.26133130e+00, 3.26059595e+00, 3.33913513e+02,
       3.86353375e+02, 6.64558635e+00, 6.49148343e+00, 6.56853489e+00,
       9.97197310e+00, 5.90360498e+01, 4.24652627e+00, 4.04987984e+00,
       5.01559151e+00, 8.06308354e+03, 8.87533489e+03, 9.68751329e+03,
       6.44093478e+03, 2.06663803e+01, 7.60477532e+01, 1.15928356e+02,
       8.80261998e+00, 9.05945819e+00, 8.80261998e+00, 8.67420088e+00,
       1.53668954e+03, 1.68568270e+03, 3.24920188e+04, 3.33137527e+04,
       3.14744302e+04, 3.08768347e+04, 2.43783246e+04, 2.60029700e+04,
       1.62551977e+04, 8.13205644e+03, 8.91520242e+00, 2.59349316e+02,
       5.68879859e+00, 5.29625257e+00, 5.31059186e+00, 3.24730609e+01,
       5.42064750e+00, 5.25564892e+00, 1.78131839e+00, 5.93866333e+00,
       2.67591702e+01, 5.45540869e+01, 7.31138255e+04, 5.43964545e+00,
       5.45398474e+00, 5.47454194e+00, 5.42317430e+00, 5.34612284e+00,
       5.19201991e+00, 5.26907138e+00, 5.01223317e+00, 4.75539496e+00,
       3.72804212e+00, 3.52257155e+00, 3.70235830e+00, 4.37013765e+00,
       5.14065227e+00, 4.88381406e+00, 5.14065227e+00, 5.11496845e+00,
       5.39749048e+00, 5.26907138e+00, 5.14065227e+00, 5.39749048e+00,
       5.14065227e+00, 5.01223317e+00, 5.44885812e+00, 5.34612284e+00,
       5.14065227e+00, 5.01223317e+00, 4.88381406e+00, 5.01223317e+00,
       4.62697585e+00, 3.98488033e+00, 5.39749048e+00, 5.19201991e+00,
       5.03791699e+00, 5.44885812e+00, 5.34612284e+00, 5.14065227e+00,
       5.39749048e+00, 5.26907138e+00, 4.98654935e+00, 5.34612284e+00,
       5.14065227e+00, 5.01223317e+00, 5.44885812e+00, 5.34612284e+00,
       5.14065227e+00, 5.39749048e+00, 5.19201991e+00, 5.01223317e+00,
       5.44885812e+00, 5.34612284e+00, 5.08928463e+00, 5.39749048e+00,
       5.26907138e+00, 5.01223317e+00, 5.39749048e+00, 5.26907138e+00,
       5.01223317e+00, 4.75539496e+00, 3.98488033e+00, 3.08594660e+00,
       5.08928463e+00, 5.01223317e+00, 5.34612284e+00, 5.19201991e+00,
       4.93518171e+00, 5.26907138e+00, 5.19201991e+00, 5.01223317e+00,
       4.49855675e+00, 4.88381406e+00, 4.49855675e+00, 4.11329944e+00,
       4.75539496e+00, 4.37013765e+00, 3.98488033e+00, 3.85646123e+00,
       3.72804212e+00, 3.34278481e+00, 5.01223317e+00, 5.34612284e+00,
       1.20282523e+01, 4.23145094e+01, 5.64638005e+01, 3.30505473e+01,
       6.29241574e+01, 1.65741931e+01, 2.34349625e+01, 1.67342859e+01,
       6.86941246e+00, 1.94359864e+01, 7.05994802e+00, 2.42076843e+01,
       8.32558913e+00, 9.08071282e+00, 1.04952078e+01, 9.74293120e+01,
       4.40468666e+02, 4.40468666e+02, 5.30955276e+02, 8.52629924e+02,
       8.17001671e+02, 1.21099115e+03, 1.21235464e+03, 1.17512283e+03,
       2.34252412e+01, 2.42478513e+01, 2.50686636e+01, 2.34714193e+01,
       2.34698783e+01, 2.34229296e+01, 2.34303779e+01, 2.34701352e+01,
       2.34665651e+01, 2.34329463e+01, 2.34267822e+01, 2.34665908e+01,
       2.42389226e+01, 4.15068602e+02, 4.69058761e+02, 3.78854341e+00,
       2.39396797e+00, 3.40402420e+00, 2.49188433e+02, 5.38674168e+03,
       1.23201827e+04, 8.68319277e+03, 1.77934328e+05, 2.37267791e+05,
       2.37738819e+05, 3.18086448e-01, 1.03160676e+02, 9.16824935e-01,
       9.17852288e-01, 1.35673279e+01, 1.35706668e+01, 3.25443666e+01,
       6.41826956e+01, 6.41744767e+01, 4.75032058e+01, 2.32993749e+01,
       2.05074263e+01, 6.93055884e+00, 8.25562994e+01, 2.65888991e+03,
       8.16922559e+00, 4.87647340e+00, 5.73734794e+01, 4.95660266e+00,
       5.59308027e+00, 6.32200520e+00, 9.40946129e+00, 2.47061701e+00,
       2.32792340e+00, 1.08030787e+00, 2.24946624e+00, 1.99543299e+00,
       1.11465177e+00, 1.69995531e+00, 2.27707050e+00, 1.18289609e+00,
       2.27500299e+00, 1.97033010e+00, 1.72109774e+00, 1.95730826e+00,
       1.55790881e+00, 4.12234391e-01, 2.07011334e+00, 1.63642572e+00,
       1.86523494e+00, 1.54635242e+00, 2.02020288e+00, 7.71660815e-01,
       1.86462807e+00, 1.50799191e+00, 5.16531961e-01, 1.62338917e+00,
       1.45514411e+00, 3.86256432e-01, 1.63345898e+00, 1.32819045e+00,
       3.49120001e-01, 1.70042593e+00, 6.84614778e-01, 2.58418250e-01,
       4.10473721e-02, 2.89904972e-01, 1.14185348e-01, 8.01477491e-01,
       5.56180967e-01, 5.29329756e-02, 1.19680461e+00, 6.09014053e-01,
       5.01229781e-01, 1.18672010e+00, 1.58351910e+00, 7.68964000e-01,
       1.19678990e+00, 2.89934385e-01, 1.04079605e+00, 8.68000282e-01,
       1.58350439e+00, 1.00320494e+00, 2.12139275e+00, 1.84180804e+00,
       1.08996452e+00, 1.85447003e+00, 1.66054115e+00, 6.69300557e-01,
       1.86453983e+00, 1.53358749e+00, 3.01606286e-01, 1.72603622e+00,
       1.60915880e+00, 5.15182924e-01, 1.81315748e+00, 1.37946985e+00,
       2.80946336e-01, 1.08392599e+00, 1.71187937e+00])
```

Как из удалить числа > 100?

Пробовал pop, remove, del, циклы, но ничего не работет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как из массива удалить числа > 100?

```
from numpy import array

data = array([1, 2, 3, 100, 101, 200])

filtered_array = [x for x in data if x <= 100]

print(filtered_array)  # [1, 2, 3, 100]
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот код который создаёт новый массив `b`, в котором все числа не превосходят сотни:

```
a = array(...)
b = a[a <= 100]
print(b)
```

**P.S.** Вы ведь с `NumPy` работаете?

Comment: я так пробовал, выдавался массива какой-то странной размерности

Comment: понимаю, что вопоос простой, но меня и удивило, почему не выходили адекватные массивы

Comment: Тогда задавайте вопрос который вас интересует ("почему странный результат?") а не какой-то вопрос рядом.

Comment: но может это ошибка моей компиляции.. поэтому и интересуюсь мнениями других

Comment: "У меня есть вопрос. Но я вам его не скажу. Задам другой лучше. Так всегда лучше получается."